# Launch multiple RStudio sessions from Docker on EC2

Tags: r, linux, docker, amazon-ec2, rstudio

I managed to install RStudio through Docker, running on port 8787 on my EC2 instance.

I wanted to add another RStudio session (not necessarily sharing the same volumes), so I tried the following:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 8788:8787 -e PASSWORD=mypassword rocker/rstudio:3.2.0
```

Which seems to work since it does not throw any error and when I do `docker ps` I see this:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                        NAMES
cb724b319ebb        rocker/rstudio:3.2.0                  "/init"                  5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:8788->8787/tcp
```

BUT when I go to http://XX.XX.XXX.XX:8788/ there is no RStudio session appearing (http://XX.XX.XXX.XX being the elastic ip adress of my ec2-server).
I made sure I added 8788 port authorized in the security group.

Do you know what I am missing?

Comment: Did you allow tcp in the firewall settings on GCP?

Comment: I did allow them on AWS yes

Comment: Maybe try `docker ps -a` to  list all containers and see if there is a port conflict? Stop if necessary. Then maybe try `docker  system prune` and try again?  I don't think this is it, but I'd need more info